# Internal website corrupts browser profile somehow

Tags: javascript, web, browser, user-profile, corrupt

At work we have an internal website which seems to, at random and rarely, stop working for a particular browser on a users computer. Might be Firefox. Might be Chrome. Whichever. It might be the reports hang (tab thread goes to 100%, needs to be killed), might be an entity management bit which stops working. All seemingly at random.

Trying Incognito/Private doesn't fix it. Trying to clear the cached files & images doesn't help. Nothing in the Developer Tools console, the Network call is showing HTTP 200 return for the call, etc. Then I tried something interesting. On one persons Chrome browser, I tried "Open Guest Window". That worked.

My conclusion is, somehow, something corrupts a bit of the user profile which somehow only affects just our website. Am I off? Is there somewhere I can look to  corroborate this hypothesis?

We're running some older version of Angular, older versions of Jetty with Spring/JAX-RS backend, etc.

I'm getting a bit desperate here, as a small bit of the site services external clients so they can see their stats, and we're getting reports from a couple of them that this is happening to them too. Any possibility that can be checked would be appreciated.

Comment: A web page shouldn't be able to do anything to the user's profile. I suspect they have a bad browser extension added. Does it happen if you disable all extensions?

Comment: `tab thread goes to 100%, needs to be killed` I suspect you have a memory leak somewhere in your javascript, that's why you should profile your programs at first place. You can easily collect memory usage from browsers today, I'll tel you refer to the different API yourself.

Comment: @Barmer, that's what I would have thought. Tried disabling browser extensions. Thing is, in Guest Window, all the extensions are still active, right? So doesn't seem like that should be it.

Comment: @mpm, I wouldn't think it'd be memory leak, it'd be missing an exit condition, otherwise the tab would crash. At least that's my experience with Java OOM vs endless loop sucking up CPU. I did try and do profiling from the Chrome Dev Tools, but not sure if I did it correctly. It didn't display any results, even after I killed the tab from the Chrome Task Manager :(   I'll try using a known good browser, see what that shows.

Comment: ` otherwise the tab would crash` no it wouldn't it would just freeze. But it's impossible to tell without looking at the code anyway.